# Starting new transaction in MS SQL fails

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I am  stuck on the following problem. Starting a new transaction after calling a stored procedure gives me "SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session." If I remove the call of that procedure all work out just fine.

The procedure does not start any transaction only reads data.

Some people suggest enabling MultipleActiveResultSets http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php but that does not solve the problem.

So the question is how calling a stored procedure may affect starting new transaction in my case.

There is the proc http://pastie.org/9718368

Comment: Are you doing anything over a linked server?

Comment: No, direct connection.

Comment: As a general note, we prefer the code to be *in the question*, not on a link to a site where the code could disappear at any time. Questions are meant to be useful not just to you, here and now, but also to future visitors to the site.